# Gtk+ mouse pointer leave-area event

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtkmm

I need to detect when the mouse pointer leaves an area in a GtkNotebook. Normally this is possible with the motion_notify event, but if the pointer is moved fast enough, the event is not triggered. Because this is a certain area of pixels in a GtkNotebook, it is not possible to use a GtkEventBox. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I want to know when I leave an area, not the whole control.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `enter-notify-event` and `leave-notify-event` signals.

Comment: These aren't working for me, and anyway, I want to know when I leave an area, not the whole control.

Answer (score 2):

You are guaranteed to get enter and leave notifications, but only periodic motion notifications. if the pointer is moving fast enough, you won't get a notification for coordinates within the area you care about.

The only way to catch this 100% is to bulid an EventBox (or some other windowed widget) into your widget hierarchy that does encapsulate this space. Keep in mind that you may be able to define the region in terms of *multiple* widgets.

Finally, if you aren't receiving enter or leave notifications from a widget, you likely have to modify the widget's event mask.

```
myWidget->add_events(Gdk::ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK);
```

Comment: Wow --- can't believe I never even realized I'd have to modify an event mask to do this. I didn't know there *was* one. I'll have to take a look at that. Thank you